# C Global Struct error. Difficulty assigning values

Tags: c, struct

I am having difficulty with assigning values to my global structure (pixel[3]). I have tried many different combinations with typedef and not, but still can't figure it out. I want three structs of pixel of type flag_struct. This top portion is my global section and function prototypes:
    #include 
    #include

```
struct flag_struct
 {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
 }pixel[3];

bool checkInputs(int argc, int countryCode, int width);
int computeHeight(int width, int countryCode);
void printFlag(int width, int height, int countryCode, struct flag_struct pixel[]);
void make_pixel (int r, int g, int b);
void flagColor(int width, int height, int countryCode);
```

This is the function in my code that is giving me the error for each line of pixel[]... Each error states: error: expected expression before â]â token.

```
void flagColor(int width, int height, int countryCode)
{
    if (countryCode == 1)
            pixel[] = 0,85,164, 255,255,255,250,60,50;
    else if (countryCode == 2)
            pixel[] = 0,0,0, 255,0,0, 255,204,0;
    else if (countryCode == 3)
            pixel[] = 253,185,19, 0,106,68, 193,39,45;

    printFlag(width, height, countryCode, pixel);

            return;
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There may be shorter versions but this should work.

```
typedef struct flag_struct
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} flag_struct;

flag_struct pixel[3];
```

And then

```
void flagColor(int width, int height, int countryCode)
{
    if (countryCode == 1) {
        pixel[0].r = 0;
        pixel[0].g = 85;
        pixel[0].b = 164; 

        pixel2[1].r = 255;
        //...
        pixel[2].b = 50;
    }
    else if (countryCode == 2) {
        // Same as above
    }
    else if (countryCode == 3) {
        // Same as above
    } 

    printFlag(width, height, countryCode, pixel);

    return;
}
```

Or you can try

```
pixel[0] = (flag_struct) { .r = 255, .g = 255, .b  = 255 };
pixel[1] = (flag_struct) { .r = 255, .g = 255, .b  = 255 };
pixel[2] = (flag_struct) { .r = 255, .g = 255, .b  = 255 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't set structs that way.  You can INITIALIZE structs with something like this,

```
struct flag_s {
  int r,g,b;
} pixel[] = { {.r=1, .g=2, .b=3}, {4, 5, 6} };
```

but you can only do that when the struct is created.

One way to set the values of your array of structs would be line-by-line:

```
pixel[0].r = 1;
pixel[0].g = 2;
pixel[0].b = 3;
pixel[1].r = 4;
pixel[1].g = 5;
```

However, I would try and take a bit of a different approach.  Consider initializing the types of flags you might need as constants and setting your global flag to those.  A typedef helps with clarity.  Something like this:

```
// typedef the struct for clarity
typedef struct flag_s {
  int r,g,b;
} flag;

// some possible flags
const flag red_flag   = {255, 0,   0  };
const flag green_flag = {0,   255, 0  };
const flag blue_flag  = {0,   0,   255};

// our global flag variable
flag f;

// set the flag by country code
void set_flag(int country_code)
{
  if (country_code == 1)
    // copy from our pre-defined flag constants
    f = red_flag;
  else if (country_code == 2)
    f = green_flag;
  else if (country_code == 3)
    f = blue_flag;
}

// print the global flag
void print_flag()
{
  printf("%d %d %d\n", f.r, f.g, f.b);
}

// try it out!
int main(int narg, char *arg[])
{
  set_flag(1);
  print_flag();
  set_flag(2);
  print_flag();
  set_flag(3);
  print_flag();

  return 0;
}
```